# A correct approach to minimizing a function of many variables

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I have a function of four variables that I'd like to minimize. However, I am not entirely sure if what I gave Mathematica to calculate is correct. Would you mind checking my expression?

```
term = (a^2 b)/2+(a b^2)/2+c^3/6+(3 b d^2)/4-(b e^2)/4-e^3/6+c^2 (a-b/4-d/2-e/2-f/2)+(ef f)/2+(3 b f^2)/4+d (-a b-(b e)/2+e^2/2-(b f)/2)+c (-a b+(b d)/2+(b e)/2+e^2/2+(b f)/2)+e (ef/2-(b f)/2-f^2/2)
Simplify[Minimize[{term,b>=c>e>=0 && a>=d>f>=0},{c,d,e,f}]]
```

So to sum up, variables are: $c,d,e,f$. All are greater or equal to zero. While $b\geq c>e$ and $a\geq d>f$, where $a,b\geq 0$ are constants.

I have seen other posts also using `Assuming` however I do not fully understand the difference between using it and not.

Comment: Whta is `(ef f)`  and `ef/2`?

Comment: It's the output I got from using `ExpandAll` and `Collect`. 

`(ef f)` is just `(ef^2)` - do I need to correct that? Similarly, `ef/2` is just `(ef)/2`. However, I thought that the Mathematica recognizes that as well?

Comment: I think `(ef f)` should be `(e f^2)` or `e*f^2` and  `ef/2` should be `e f/2` or `e*f/2`.

Comment: Other than that, the way I have written the problem is correct? It is my first attempt at Mathematica and I am not sure how long I can expect the minimization of four variables to take. I'd expect the third-degree polynomial to take some time - however how long can I expect the minimization process to last? Is there any rule?